# Date comparison in shell

Tags: bash, shell

This command will list certificates with dates.

```
keytool -list -v -keystore /path to file/truststore-sit.jks -storepass "password" | grep -e "Alias" -e "Valid" | grep 'until:' | sed 's/^.*until: //'
```

**Output**

```
Wed Feb 15 11:23:46 IST 2023
Thu Jun 22 05:29:59 IST 2023
Sun Oct 02 05:29:59 IST 2033
Mon Feb 12 05:29:59 IST 2024
```

I need to write a shell script where it can list certificates with dates and compare them with today's date and list expired certificate and store them a file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eux
keystore="$1"
storepass="$2"
now=$(date +%s)
keytool -list -v -keystore "$keystore" -storepass "$storepass" |
  sed -nr 's/^Alias name:\s*(.*)$/\1/p;s/Valid from:.*until: *(.*)/\1/p' |
  paste - - |
  while IFS=$'\t' read -r alias expires ; do
    expires_at=$(date -d "$expires" +%s)
    if ((expires_at < now)) ; then
      echo -e "$expires\t$alias"
    fi
done
```

Getting error:

> line 4: $1: unbound variable

I need to list the certificates and compare each certificate's date (the 4 dates as mentioned above) with today's date and list only expired certificate and send a mail message.

Comment: Check how? On which platform? Do you have GNU `date` or the BSD one (as is commonly installed on MacOS)?

Comment: What does the output from the `keystore` command look like? Your processing with [useless `grep`s](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) could almost certainly be improved, but it's hard to say how exactly without access to sample input data.

Comment: In the end, I guess you are simply looking for `keystore blah blah | awk something | while read -r date; do : your date manipulation here; done`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick solution that I came up with that should give you a start:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

keystore="$1"
storepass="$2"
now=$(date +%s)

keytool -list -v -keystore "$keystore" -storepass "$storepass" |
  sed -nr 's/^Alias name:\s*(.*)$/\1/p;s/Valid from:.*until: *(.*)/\1/p' |
  paste - - |
  while IFS=$'\t' read -r alias expires ; do
    expires_at=$(date -d "$expires" +%s)
    if ((expires_at < now)) ; then
      echo -e "$expires\t$alias"
    fi
  done
```

Just run that script with the keystone file as the first parameter and the password as the second and you should get output similar to:

```
Tue Apr 06 03:29:40 EDT 2021    debian:sonera_class_2_root_ca.pem
Thu Dec 08 06:10:28 EST 2022    debian:staat_der_nederlanden_ev_root_ca.pem
Wed Mar 25 07:03:10 EDT 2020    debian:staat_der_nederlanden_root_ca_-_g2.pem
Thu Jun 23 20:16:12 EDT 2022    debian:visa_ecommerce_root.pem
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an `awk` for listing the expired certificates from the output of `keytool -list -v`. Because it's a simple comparison, you don't even need to convert the dates to epoch:

```bash
keytool -list -v ... |

awk -F ' (name|from|until): ' -v now="$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)" '

    $1 == "Alias" { alias_name = $2 }

    $1 == "Valid" {

        # $3 -> "Mon Dec 31 14:10:36 UTC 2040"

        split($3,a,/[ :]/)
        a[2] = sprintf("%02d", (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",a[2]) + 2) / 3)

        date = a[8] a[2] a[3] a[4] a[5] a[6]
        if (date <= now)
            print alias_name
    }
'
```